# How do I handle variable storage as an object name

Tags: javascript, json, variables

I have a JSON-file with objects.

```
_1_2__1 = {
    'nodes': [
        {
            'name':'1_4',
            'cost':20
        },
        {
            'name':'3_2',
            'cost':30
        }
    ]
};
```

In my project, the client does type something in a form, which value will be transformed into the style of the object name in the JSON-file, saved in a variable (extern, in JavaScript). Now I want to have access to the properties of this objects, using the variable with the name of the object. But if I would type it like

```
Variable.properties
```

the variable would be handeled as the object, not the content of the variable. Do You know how I do use the content of the variable as the object name?

Comment: Dynamic variable names are not possible in JavaScript. Dynamic *property* names are (via the `[ ]` operator).

Comment: Well, they're possible via `eval()` but that's probably not the best approach to the problem.

Comment: When you have a callback on an AJAX request, it will return the content body of the response using whatever the content-type is (for instance, `application/json`). So you can respond with a JSON-formatted string (PHP's `json_encode($obj)` for example) and the callback will have a variable that gives you access to that data. So you don't need to create a variable.

Comment: For instance, look at [jQuery's AJAX `success() callback`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), it shows the `data` argument that gives you access to the data returned in the response body.